# jquery select the option list with dynamic id

Tags: jquery

I have an option list with an id that could sometimes be one of these:

```
edit-panes-billing-billing-zone
edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--1
edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--2
edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--3
edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--4
```

There is only one select element at a time.

Is it possible to select the option list dynamically with jQuery?
This is what I've tried, but it's not working:

```
$("select[id^='edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--']").each(function() {
    alert('test'):              
}
```

Comment: can you share your HTML code ?

Comment: what error its gave in firebug.?

Comment: jQuery may not give any error, it just found 0 element :p

Comment: @user1073122 may be OP getting and setting ids of options rather then select...

Comment: is your code wrapped in `document.ready`?

Comment: update your post with your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of failing syntax errors in your code:

```
alert('test'):
```

should be

```
alert('test');
```

And

```
alert('test'):              
}
```

should be

```
alert('test');              
});
```

The final result should be:

```
$("select[id^='edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--']").each(function() {
    alert('test');             
});
```

This succeeds in all the tests I've run.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select option[id^="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--"]').each(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give attribute class for each select that you have, for example

```
<select class="my-select" id="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone"></select>
<select class="my-select" id="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--1"></select>
<select class="my-select" id="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--2"></select>
<select class="my-select" id="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--3"></select>
<select class="my-select" id="edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--4"></select>
```

and then the code is (get the element by class) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-select").each(function() {
       alert('test');              
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a solution, but this is not solving the problem, and getting element with id has better perf. that with a CSS class

Comment: can it be selected by name? the name is panes[billing][billing_zone]

Comment: can you post the html in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear *`I have an option list with an id`*:

`option list`, i believe these are the bunch of `<select>` tags.

```
$("select[id^='edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--']").change(function() {
    alert('test'):              
});
```

of if we go with your code then you should try this way:

```
$("select[id^='edit-panes-billing-billing-zone--']").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function(){
        alert('test');
    });              
});
```

### note:

Your code is missing `});` at the end and your alert is ending with `colon-> :` not `semicolon ';'`

instead `.each()` try `.change()` event.

Comment: if alert doesn't fire within `each`, assuming no errors, there's no reason it will fire within a change handler