# when option selected do stuff ( btw, all the elments have dynamic id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched for similar questions, I found some but their solution did't help me.
For example:

[First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916465/jquery-selecting-dynamic-id)

[Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929901/jquery-select-the-option-list-with-dynamic-id)

My problem is:

I have a table that the user can add rows dynamically, so I am creating a unique id for each row and all elements inside as well.
each row have two text fields and select with two options, and when you select one of the option the text feild should be dislpay:block and the second will be display: "none", depending on your choice.

I built here some example that will shows the general structure (JSFiddle)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input id="description-first-1" name="description-first-1" type="text" placeholder = "first">
        <input id="description-second-1" name="description-second-2" type="text" placeholder = "second">
            <select id="select-1">
                <option>
                        <option id="first-opt-1">1</option>
                        <option id="second-opt-1">2</option>
                </option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
        <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="description-first-2" name="description-first-1" type="text" placeholder = "first">
        <input id="description-second-2" name="description-second-2" type="text" placeholder = "second">
            <select id="select-2">
                <option>
                        <option id="first-opt-2">1</option>
                        <option id="second-opt-2">2</option>
                </option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
$(function() {
        $("#select-1").change(function() {
            if ($("#first-opt-1").is(":selected")) {
                $("#description-first-1").show();
                $("#description-second-1").hide();
            } else {
                $("#description-first-1").hide();
                $("#description-second-2").show();
            }
        }).trigger('change');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vz121rq/9/

In my example for that matter you can seen that there are only 2 rows but it can also be 10 rows with different id's.

How to get jquery identify which row and all the elements inside of it i'm changing if the id's of all elements is dynamic ?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have jquery included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need event delegation as the rows are dynamically generated, such as:

```
$("table").on("change", "[id^='select']", function() {
    // do your stuf
});
```

Or in your case:

```
$("table").on("change", "#select-1", function() {
    // do your stuf
});
```

So, is this what you needed?

```
$(function() {
    $("table").on("change", "[id^='select']", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $row = $this.closest("tr");
        var ID = this.id.replace(/^[^\-]+\-(\d+)$/gi, '$1');
        var sIndex = $this.prop('selectedIndex');
        var part = sIndex === 2 ? "second" : "first";
        if (!sIndex) {
            $row.find("input").show();
            return;
        }

        $row.find("input").hide();
        $row.find("#description-" + part + "-" + ID).show();            
    });
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/8vz121rq/7/)

P.S. The above is purely based on your markup and ID structure!

Comment: Thanks for the response! but I manage to catch only the first options

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! can't give you +1 my reputation not high enough :)